# Git GUI client for Windows

Tags: windows, gui, git

I'm looking for a Git GUI client for Windows PC.

Preferably:

- Visual Commit History
- Built-In Code Editor
- Able to Resolve merge conflicts in-app
- Simple & light Weight
- Open Source
- Markdown Support

Comment: Have you seen the Git GUI clients here: https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows

Comment: What counts as "code editor", do you mean "text editor" or do you have a specific language in mind that you want tooling for?